# How save data from single form to two models in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models: Tenant and User. Every tenant may have many users. My current difficulty is with signup functionality. Via the form I can enter data for both models, but when I press Save button I'm getting an exception "undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass" for callback before_validation in User model. In debugging I see that tenant_params[:users_attributes] is empty and this is the reason for exception. What I don't understand is why this is empty? And how should I do to successfully save both tenant and user? I'm new to Rails and already spent several days trying different options without luck, so any help is appreciated.

Signup form looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@tenant) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/tenant_error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name_orig, "Company name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_orig, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email, "Company e-mail" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= fields_for(:user, @tenant.users.build) do |u| %>

    <%= u.label :name, "User name" %>
    <%= u.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :email, "User e-mail" %>
    <%= u.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :password, "Password" %>
    <%= u.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
    <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Tenant model:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :tenant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users    

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0 
    self.name = name_orig.upcase 
    email.downcase!
  end

  validates :name_orig, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :users
  validates_presence_of :tenant

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A\w+\s?\w*\z/i
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
                    format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  validates :tenant_id, presence: true

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

Tenant controller:

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @tenant.users.build
  end

  def create        
    @tenant = Tenant.new(tenant_params)
    @tenant.save

    @user = @tenant.users.build(tenant_params[:users_attributes])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @tenant   # redirects to tenant profile
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

    def tenant_params
      params.require(:tenant).permit(:name_orig, :email,
          users_attributes: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end

end
```

Comment: <%= fields_for(:user, @tenant.users.build) do |u| %> could probably be refined to <%= f.fields_for(:users do |u| %> and when you save the @tenant instance, it should automatically save the user data from the params hash so you can omit the explicit building and saving of a user in the create function in your TenantsController.

Comment: I think `users_attributes` in your `tenant_params` definition should just be `user`. Try inspecting `params` itself to see if the data *is* coming in, but being filtered out.

Comment: @hypern Thank you! You made my day! There is no more runtime exception. But when I save @tenance instance I get validation error "Users tenant can't be blank" due to `validates :tenant_id, presence: true` in User model.

Comment: That just means the tenant_id isn't being passed to the User model.  Make sure your controller is whitelisting that parameter before passing it into User.create.

Comment: @bkunzi01, the form does not contain :tenant_id, so there is no sense in whitelisting it. The problem is somehow related to validation because if I remove `validates :tenant_id, presence: true` from User model then saving @tenant instance correctly writes both tenant and user data to the database, and user has tenant_id correctly assigned.

Comment: Change validates :tenant_id, presence: true to validates :tenant, presence: true. You shouldn't check the presence of a foreign key, but rather the object itself. If you want to validate the user attributes too, make sure you include inverse_of: :tenant in your has_many :users association

Comment: You can find the explanation about presence validation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)